# How to get working path of a wcf application?

Tags: wcf, path, httpcontext

I want to get the working folder of a WCF application. How can I get it?

If I try

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)
```

I get a null reference exception (the Http.Current object is null).

---

What I meant with the working folder was the folder where my WCF service is running. If I set `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"`, I get this error:

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I needed the same information for my IIS6 hosted WCF application and I found that this worked for me:

```
string apPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```

As always, YMMV.

Comment: This solution worked best for me - I'd recommend using it rather than having to make all kinds of other settings changes...

Comment: I don't have System.Web.Hosting , I really don't know the reason why . . .

Comment: Thanks ongle :) I'm success with using AppDomain :)

Comment: @nXqd: You need to ensure that you've not got the Client Profile version of the framework selected.

Comment: This answer just saved my day. Please make it the accepted one, since using ASP.NET Compatibility is not always preferred. This one works regardless of ASP.NET Compatibility being on or off.

Comment: This solution helped me.

Answer (score 32):

**Please see ongle's answer below. It is much better than this one.**

*Updated after more information*

The following worked for me. I tested it with a new WCF Service I hosted on IIS through a Service1.svc.

1. Add `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>` to web config. `<system.serviceModel>..</ ..>` existed already.
2. Add `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute` to the service with Mode Allowed.
3. Use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".");` to get the root directory.

Below is the full code for the service class. I made no changes in the IService1 interface.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".");
    }
}
```

And below is an excerpt from the web.config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!-- Added only the one line below -->
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

    <!-- Everything else was left intact -->
    <behaviors>
        <!-- ... -->
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <!-- ... -->
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Old answer**

What do you mean by the Working Folder? WCF services can be hosted in several different ways and with different endpoints so working folder is slightly ambiguous.

You can retrieve the normal "Working folder" with a call to [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx).

HttpContext is an ASP.Net object. Even if WCF can be hosted on IIS, it's still not ASP.Net and for that reason most of the ASP.Net techniques do not work by default. OperationContext is the WCF's equivalent of HttpContext. The OperationContext contains information on the incoming request, outgoing response among other things.

Though the easiest way might be to run the service in [ASP.Net compatibility mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx) by toggling it in the web.config. This should give you access to the ASP.Net HttpContext. It will limit you to the *HttpBindings and IIS hosting though. To toggle the compatibility mode, add the following to the web.config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What I meant with the "Working folder" was the physical path where my WCF service was running. I have a xml file there and I want to read it.

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() is not working, and when I try the setting you said about compatibility mode I get this error:
The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

Comment: use this which works with both ASPNET context or without System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/folder/file");

Comment: The AspNetCompatibilityMode won't work if you have to access HttpContext.Current in a method which is called via multithreading.

Answer (score 21):

Depending on what you want. I usually want to resolve a url like "~/folder/file". This is what worked.

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/folder/file");
```

Answer (score 19):

More general, I am using this one

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: +one for a solution without System.Web

Answer (score 12):

The aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" should have resolved my problem, but I got this error:

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

I resolved my problem with getting the physical path of my running WCF service by getting it from my current app domain:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: If you run ServiceHost manually then only AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory points to correct source. Thx man !

Answer (score 3):

In order to reference ASP.NET features like the HttpContext object, you need to run your WCF app in ASP.NET compatibility mode.  This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx) explains how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath in WCF to find your application physical path.
Use namespace 
using System.Web.Hosting;