# Getting physical path of the file in wcf service

Tags: wcf

Server.mappath is not working in wcf? what is the alternate way to get the physical location of the file in IIS.?

Answer (score 7):

Best answered in this thread: [How to get working path of a wcf application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791468/how-to-get-working-path-of-a-wcf-application)

Basically, use this to get the working directory:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
```

Comment: Do you know if this still works as of 2017? I can't find System.Web.Hosting in my references.

Comment: Perhaps you are not referencing System.Web?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236721/cant-add-reference-to-system-web-hosting