# can't add reference to System.Web.Hosting

Tags: c#

I am migrating a web application from VB to C#. I have also upgraded to Update 3 in VS2013. Were there changes to the `Hosting` class? I'm getting an error using `Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath` and I can't even add a reference to `System.Web.Hosting` as it's nowhere to be found. When I try to search the assemblies when adding a reference, using the whole namespace i.e. `System.Web.Hosting`, it returns no result.

I have the using statement in the class and it is NOT grayed out meaning it is being used for something but yet the code doesn't like `Hosting` in `Hosting.HostingEnvironment` as it's in glaring red. I don't even get the `Hosting` class in intellisense and the project has a reference to `System.Web`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `Hosting` class. Instead, you want the `HostingEnvironment` class:

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Hello.txt");
```

The full type of `HostingEnvironment` is `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment`, so you need to have a `using System.Web.Hosting;` clause in the file, or use the full name.

Even more importantly, though, if you're making a web application, you most likely don't want to use `HostingEnvironment` anyway. You should always have an instance of e.g. `HttpContext` or `Page` / `Control`, which give you access to `Server.MapPath`, which should be preferred.

As for the reference, `System.Web.Hosting` namespace lives in `System.Web.dll`, so just make sure you have a reference to that and you should be fine.

Since you're migrating this from VB, I assume that the conflict is caused by VB's different treatment of namespaces. In C#, you can't just do this:

```
using System.Web;

Hosting.HostingEnvironment.DoWhatever();
```

When using a namespace, either use the full type name including the namespace, or use a using on the exact namespace, and the type. Combining the two doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, was something other than what is posted. I was looking at code in a library in a separate (Model) project. In the library project I was using, System.Web wasn't referenced.

The tricky part was that `System.Web.Http` was referenced, so the System.Web namespace was found, so the statement `using System.Web;` compiled fine.

Save yourself some trouble and heartache, always press the "Sync with Active Document" button in the Solution Explorer, as depicted in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30517179/149884

Comment: As an aside, the Model class needed System.Web.Hosting to throw an async "Fire & Forget" message using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` on exception that wouldn't get killed by IIS recycling the worker process.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try with [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) in System.Web ?

Comment: That doesn't really solve the issue, does it? What if OP needs to use another member of that class/namespace?

Comment: @Stijn probably because there is no Hosting class ?

Comment: This is the issue I'm having, I need the QueueBackgroundWorkItem method in the HostingEnvironment class. I can see the namespace, class and method in the object browser, but my code doesn't find it when referencing the 4.5.2 version of System.Web.Hosting,

Comment: @Michael, why not address the 4.5.1 assemblies or skip to 4.6.1.  I found targeting 4.5.2 generally problematic.

Comment: In my case, Sharepoint 2013 doesn't play nice with 4.6. But I'm definitely feeling the "pinch" of targeting 4.5.2.

I was looking at the references in my WebAPI project, but the code that I was looking at was in a different library project that didn't have those references. I've added an answer documenting this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the .NET Client Profile to build Web Applications?

Anyway, that aside. You find that namespaces tend to be re-used across different assemblies. Especially in the framework assemblies where they believe some classes conceptually belong together even if they support different technologies.

I am not sure I explained that well but take this example.  There is a System namespace in mscorlib, System, System.Net, System.Core and System.Numerics.  Also, System.Web may show up in System.Web.Http, or System.Web itself, and others like System.Web.Abstractions, System.Web.Optimization, etc. As a result just trying to use a using statement to discern the assembly a particular class came from can really throw you off.

The typical classes in the System.Web.Hosting namespace are in the framework assembly System.Web.dll.  Microsoft has been trying to de-emphasize the direct use of System.Web.dll in favor of the more modular implementation of Katana/Kestrel.

Having said that, make sure your project directly references System.Web.dll. To use the required class either refer to it by its complete name ie System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.  Or put a `using System.Web.Hosting;` at the beginning of your .cs file.

It is possible to have a property in the current class that is named HostingEnvironment, or a class from another namespace in another assembly that is named HostingEnvironment. In that instance, you may need to specify the class name in full or come up with a moniker for easy reference and to reduce typing.

For instance, you could have this at the beginning of your file:

```
using HostEnv = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment;
```

Then somewhere in the body of your code, you could make reference to it thus:

```
var appHost = HostEnv.ApplicationHost;
```

Does this help?

For the particular scenario you want to address, you may then do this:

```
var resolvedPath = HostEnv.MapPath(pathToMap);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your library profile from client.

[Changing client profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx)