# HttpContext.Current is null in my web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, inputstream, httpcontext

I have a web service (.svc), and I am trying to capture the SOAP request using a piece of code found elsewhere on StackOverflow.

The problem is that `HttpContext.Current` is null, so I can't access `Request.InputString`.

Why is this null, and how can it be solved?

```
XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();

Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
receiveStream.Position = 0;

using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    xmlSoapRequest.Load(readStream);
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want to use `HttpContext` because the code has already been written as so; you need to add this to your web.config where your service resides:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you. We have prebuilt classes looking for the httpcontext. FYI I also had to add the following preceding my Service class definition -->      [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

Comment: Work like a charm!

Comment: Worked for me, after long head banging. Thanks a lot  !!!

Answer (score 16):

From one of [Microsoft's pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) on the subject.

> HttpContext: Current is always null when accessed from within a WCF
>   service. Use RequestContext instead.

Answer (score 2):

Correct else use below to read header

```
 var headers = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["httpRequest"];
                var apiToken = ((HttpRequestMessageProperty)headers).Headers["apiKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current is null when accessed from a web service.  Use HttpRuntime.Cache instead.

Answer (score -4):

Please see [How to get working path of a wcf application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791468/how-to-get-working-path-of-a-wcf-application)
Use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath`