# HttpContext.Current.User is null when IsOneWay = true

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, forms-authentication, isoneway

I have wcf services. Some of them are one way, some are not.
Those that are not one way work with forms authentication and i get HttpContext.Current.User.
Those that are one way get a null in HttpContext.Current.User.

How to fix?

I am using ASP.NET Compatibility Mode

Answer (score 1):

Via [HttpContext.Current is null in my web service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8976797/266143):

> [WCF Services and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)
>
> Within an AppDomain, features implemented by the HTTP runtime apply to ASP.NET content but not to WCF. Many HTTP-specific features of the ASP.NET application platform do not apply to WCF Services hosted inside of an AppDomain that contains ASP.NET content. Examples of these features include the following:
>
> `HttpContext`: `Current` is always null when accessed from within a WCF service. Use `RequestContext` instead.
>
> [...]
>
> HttpContext: WCF services running in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode can access Current and its associated state.

Comment: you mean `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext1` ? this one is also null. Anyway I need to access to the 'HttpContext.Current.User' property.

Comment: _"Anyway I need to access to the 'HttpContext.Current.User' property."_ - no, you need to get the currently logged on user. If that is not in that property and that is documented, you need to look somewhere else. Also see edit, take a look at ASP.NET Compatibility Mode.

Comment: Well perhaps then it's useful to edit your question with what you have tried and what your configuration is, if you don't want this to become a game of guess.