# How to check whether or not a folder is exist on the server through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, httpwebrequest

I want to know that is there any property or method by which i come to know that a folder is there on the server.

just like if i have this in my web.config:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="ImagePath" value="http://server1:801/ImageById/"/>
</appSettings>
```

and i am getting this key like this:

```
var URL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"].ToString();
```

Now i want to know that how to access imageById on the server and save something into this.
just like below:

```
if("Folder exist on this server URL that is ImageById")
{
save images to the folder thorugh code of WCF as the folder has write permission.
}
```

and i want this functionality in WCF not in ASP.NET.

please help.

Comment: do you mean is there a way that a client can check if a folder exists on the server?

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("ImabgeById")))
    {
      save images to the folder thorugh code of WCF as the folder has write permission.
    }
```

also this can be of help
[How to get working path of a wcf application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791468/how-to-get-working-path-of-a-wcf-application)

Comment: everything is fine i am getting the values and saving the values but how to give user or client a url path where images are saving so that they can access that

Comment: i will check it as answer just checking it from my side and then will let u know

Comment: Hi act i have another problem now i am getting error 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.''
that problem is resolved by creating a directory programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.IO.Directory.Exists(*path*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) - you simply need to ensure that your WCF service is operating under credentials with adequate permissions to get to the folder in question (otherwise you will encounter an exception).

Comment: in this what should be the path as if i am giving the path same as what i am getting in URL it is giving me exception of URI Format are not allowed

Comment: @AbhishekMathur You need to convert the URL to a proper file path that is either relative to the location of your WCF service or is absolute. In any case that is a different question, try looking here on SO for previous questions about mapping a URL to a file path - it's been covered lots of times.