# ApplicationPhysicalPath is null?

Tags: c#, wcf

When my Windows Service(WCF service in selfhost) is starting up(`ServiceBase.Main`) I got some code that needs to know the `ApplicationPhysicalPath`.

The problem is that `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` is always `null`?

Why? And is there any workaround?

Comment: What Platform is the server running on?

Comment: Windows 7, Webservce, .net 4.0, Selfhost, Windows Service.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791468/how-to-get-working-path-of-a-wcf-application help?

Comment: No it does not, none of the top 2 answers solves the problem :(

Comment: Did you check the third answer? Seems to be the best solution according to the community

Comment: The ongle is the second for me but no that does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its null because a Windows Service has nothing to do with Web hosting (unless you create a WCF ServiceHost inside it that's configured with an http binding).

How about just falling back to `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Assembly.CodeBase or Assembly.Location instead?

```
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```